# Ruby mysql gem inserting unicode string into mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby, unicode, arabic

So i have some Unicode(Arabic) text data stored in a Mongoid model and i want to insert it into a mysql database. I had to use gsub to escape single quotes as that was causing me SQL insertion errors.

```
text = model.text.squish().gsub("'", %q(\\\'))
db_con.query("insert into table (text) values ('#{text}')")
```

Now my problem is when i view the data at phpmyadmin this what i see

> Ø§Ù„ÙŠÙˆÙ….. Ù…Ù„Ø§ÙŠÙŠÙ† Ø§Ù„Ù‡ÙˆØ§ØªÙ ØªÙˆØ¯Ø¹ "ÙˆØ§ØªØ³Ø§Ø¨"
>   Ù„Ù„Ø£Ø¨Ø¯

I tried adding `force_encoding('UTF-8')` but that didn't change anything, i also tried escaping with `str.dump` but that transformed the data into Unicode code points like u{243} when viewed in phpmyadmin. How can this be fixed.

Comment: Make sure all your encodings agree _before_ you put the data in.  If you use a default charset of non-unicode, and then insert unicode data, mysql won't know it will be unicode and will store the same bytes but not convert to unicode ( because you told it it was already in unicode).

Comment: In the database structure the Collation is "utf8_general_ci".

Comment: Collation is just for alphabetical order.  What is the default _charset_?  Or more accurately, what charset was your unicode data inserted with?

Comment: Ah i just checked the information schema  schemata, the default charset is utf-8, the data should have been inserted as UTF8 as well, its important to note that this data is displayed correctly in the Rails C and the views in my Rails app, and in the mongo shell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831 -- look for "Mojibake"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by executing this query before insertion "SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'"

```
text = model.text.squish().gsub("'", %q(\\\'))
db_con.query("SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'")
db_con.query("insert into table (text) values ('#{text}')")
```